# ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add this code to my application initializer for my Rails application.  But some things that I'm reading / researching is advising that I place this call in my environment.rb file(s), while other information is advising that I place this in my application.rb file(s).

Which one is the correct location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it doesn't matter. Some people will create a `config` file, other will just include it in the code. Having a config file does make it easier to keep track of everything, and keeps it all in the same place. But as far as performance, it doesn't matter.